# Creating clusters of nearby points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, clustering

I m trying to create clusters of nearby points (which would be the adresses of my customers around a store). 
Buffer is not an option cauz i need the zone to be limited by customers, so a polygone shape not round
I've tried the convex hull but then my attibute table is empty and I need all the associated data inside the shape
I've also tried contour but i have 500 stores and i need to do it for each store separately
The point to polygone extension considers all the points together

Does someone have an idea of how to do this?

I'm working on QGIS 2.0.1.

Comment: What would be the determining factor for your clusters? A variable (population) or just spatial proximity? You found this post and have tried out the answers? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11342/how-to-identify-clusters-in-vector-point-data?rq=1

Comment: I am faily new to QGIS and I'm not sure if i d be able to use PostGIS or Python... The clusters I'm trying to determine are just spatial proximity. But I don't want to specify a radius cauz I don't know from how far the customer are coming. I  m not sure if I'm being very clear but to give you an idea, i'd like to select some points manually and transform them into a polygone but keeping all the associated data. Can i do it manually? Is there a more efficient way too for 500 stores?

Comment: what is your problem with convex hull ? the shape or the absence of specific attributes from the points ?

Comment: The shape is fine, the problem is the abscence of data associated with the points that the shape covers