# Find number of weighted point clusters & centre of clusters

Tags: qgis, clustering, spatial-cluster

I have a points layer with a frequency field indicating a population at that point. There is also a field indicating the broader area by which I need to analysis broken down into. I am expecting the points to be mostly grouped in a number of clusters. I need a way of determining how many clusters there are, probably by density, and to return a point for the centre of each.

I've made a heatmap in the display section of the points layer by setting a radius and weighting by the frequency field and in this created three clusters in my trial area, that look right, but I don't see how to get a coordinate for them. Any suggestions of what tool(s) to look at.

---

[Identifying clusters in vector point data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11342/identifying-clusters-in-vector-point-data-using-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)  is basically the same, but as none of the answers explain how I can do weighted cluster analysis in QGIS.  I don't know postGIS or R, and the plugin manageR that was cited no longer seems to exist.